# Erase an array - is it necessary?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Please have a look at the code below:

```
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OracleClient

Public Class clsParameterValues
    Implements IDisposable

    Private paramValues(0) As DbParameter

    Public Function AssignParameterValues(ByVal strParameterName As String, ByVal strParameterValue As String, ByVal intDatabaseType As Integer) As Integer
        Dim intArrayBound As Integer

        intArrayBound = UBound(paramValues)
        If intArrayBound > 0 Then
            ReDim paramValues(intArrayBound)
        End If

        If intDatabaseType = 1 Then

            paramValues(intArrayBound) = New SqlParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
        ElseIf intDatabaseType = 2 Then
            paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(strParameterName, strParameterValue)
            'paramValues(intArrayBound) = New OracleParameter(":" & strParameterName, OracleType.Int32)
            'paramValues(intArrayBound).Value = strParameterValue
        End If
        Return intArrayBound
    End Function

    Public Function getParameterValues() As DbParameter()
        Return paramValues
    End Function

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Erase paramValues
        paramValues = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

The webpage function looks like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim objParameterValues As New clsParameterValues
                Using objParameterValues
                    'Use the objParameterValues class here.
                End Using
                objParameterValues=nothing
            End Using
End Sub
```

I am using `IDisposable.Dispose` to erase the array before setting it to `Nothing`. I believe this is bad practice because the Array class does not implement `IDisposable`. Is it even necessary to erase an array and set it to `Nothing`? (Does the garbage collector deal with this?)

Comment: On a related side note, you should only use `IDisposable` if your instance data does (or you have some unmanaged resources yourself such as an OS handle).  It is not needed otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Erase paramValues
    paramValues = Nothing
End Sub
```

The Erase statement dates from old versions of Basic, the kind where manual memory management was useful.  No more, memory management is automatic in .NET.  It is still supported for compatibility reasons.  All it does is set the array reference to Nothing.  So your code is equivalent to:

```
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    paramValues = Nothing
    paramValues = Nothing
End Sub
```

So no point to it.  You should *never* implement IDisposible to set a variable to Nothing, that's not the interface's contract.  A disposed object may never be used again.  So no point in setting the array reference to null since that doesn't actually do anything to the real array object on the garbage collected heap.  I cannot otherwise see a scenario where you would want to help, any clsParameterValues object should have a limited lifetime.  It just isn't useful anymore when you null the array reference.

Just remove the IDisposable implementation.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for showing what Dispose is actually doing in my case i.e. setting paramValues to nothing twice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even necessary to erase an array and set it to nothing?

No. The GC does that in its own time. <del>In fact, I’m not even sure whether `Erase` actually frees money or whether it simply points the array somewhere else.</del>It just sets the variable to `Nothing`. `Erase` probably exists out of compatibility with VB6. C# for instance doesn’t have it (and neither does it have `ReDim`, although `Array.Resize` exists of course, albeit with slightly different semantics).

On the other hand, if your array contained `IDisposable` objects (which it doesn’t) you should dispose *those* in your `Dispose` method by iterating over the array and disposing them in turn. But again, the array *itself* doesn’t need to be erased.

As a general remark, your code reads very much like VB6. Change that. Don’t declare variables without initialising them. Don’t use `UBound` etc (there’s the `.Length` property instead). If you find yourself using `ReDim` very often use a `System.Collections.Generic.List` instead of an array.

Comment: side note: The Erase statement is equivalent to assigning Nothing to each array variable.

Comment: @DominicKexel: [The Erase statement is equivalent to assigning Nothing to each array variable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zyeke9(v=vs.80).aspx)